# Closed sets in metric spaces.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d(x,y)=$ $|\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{y}{1+y}|$ be a metric on $[0,\infty)$ Show that $F$ is closed in $([0,\infty) , d)$ $\iff$ $F$ is closed in $([0,\infty)), |.|)$

My idea is to use the sequence characterisation for first countable spaces. I.e if $\{$ $x_n$ $\}$ is a sequence of points in $F$ that converge to $x\in X$  then because $F$ is closed, $x\in F$.

The second thing I have tried is to show that the metrics are equivalent, and I was indeed able to get:

$|\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{y}{1+y}|\leq |x-y|$ for any $x,y\in [0,\infty)$

So, how would I get the other inequality? I thought that I should use the reverse triangle inequality, but that got me nowhere as well.

May I have hints, please?

Comment: $\frac{|x-y|}{|(1+\max(x,y))^2|}\leq |\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{y}{1+y}|$. This inequality tells you that inside any open $d$-ball centered at $y$ there is an open $|\cdot|$-ball centered at $y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You won’t be able to prove that the two distances are equivalent... as they are not. The issue is that the distance of two points for $d$ may converges towards zero while being fixed for $\vert \cdot \vert$. Consider $x_n =n$ and $y_n= n+1$ for example where $n \in \mathbb N$.

However, the application $\varphi(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is a differentiable increasing map from $[0,\infty)$ onto $[0,1)$. Hence it is a bijection between those two intervals. Moreover on a finite closed interval $[a,b]$, you have $$0 <\varphi^\prime(b) \le \varphi^\prime(x) \le \varphi^\prime(a) \le 1$$ for $x \in [a,b]$. Using the Mean Value Theorem, you can prove that $\varphi$ is lipschitz and that the two distances are equivalent on bounded intervals.

Finally, you can use above result to prove that an open subset is open for one distance if and only if it is open for the other one. Which allows to conclude using the complements.